# Unable to update weights in my Pytorch model when I compute loss with my own data structure

Tags: pytorch, loss-function

My model gflowfigure8 takes a step and produces a value for `forward_prob` among other things in each step. If I directly use the value from the returned step to compute loss and backpropogate my model's weights get updated.

However, I need to be able to store these results in my `trajectory` data structure and calculate a loss using this trajectory. When I try doing this I am unable to update the weights of my model. I would like to be able to update the weights.

train.py

```
for _ in range(num_epochs):
        trajectory = Trajectory()
        gflowfigure8._reset_agents()
        
        steps_in_trajectory = 1
        for _ in range(steps_in_trajectory):   
            for a_id in range(config['custom_model_config']['nred']):
                step = gflowfigure8.step(a_id)
                trajectory.add_step(
                    forward_prob=step['forward_prob'],
                    backward_prob=step['backward_prob'],
                    flow=step['flow'],
                    action=step['action'],
                    reward=step['step_reward'],
                    node=step['node']
                )
        # This works to update the gradient
        # episode_loss = losses.Losses.step_test(step) 

        # This does not
        episode_loss = losses.Losses.trajectory_balance(trajectory)

        batch_num = batch_num + 1
        batch_loss += episode_loss

        batch_size = 150
        if batch_num % batch_size == 0:
            if WANDB:
                wandb.log({"loss": batch_loss/batch_size})
                batch_loss = 0
                
                for name, param in gflowfigure8.sampler_fcn.named_parameters():
                    wandb.log({f"{name}_mean": param.data.mean().item(), f"{name}_std": param.data.std().item()})

        episode_loss.backward()
        optimizer.step()
        optimizer.zero_grad()
```

trajectory.py

```
class Trajectory():
    def __init__(self) -> None:
        self.log_norm_constant = 100
        self.forward_probs = torch.tensor([], requires_grad=True)
        self.backward_probs = torch.tensor([], requires_grad=True)
        self.flows = torch.tensor([], requires_grad=True)
        self.actions = torch.tensor([], requires_grad=True)
        self.rewards = torch.tensor([], requires_grad=True)
        self.nodes = torch.tensor([], requires_grad=True)
    def add_step(self, forward_prob, backward_prob, flow, action, reward, node):
        self.forward_probs = torch.cat((self.forward_probs, torch.tensor([forward_prob]))) 
        self.backward_probs = torch.cat((self.backward_probs, torch.tensor([backward_prob]))) 
        self.flows = torch.cat((self.flows, torch.tensor([flow]))) 
        self.nodes = torch.cat((self.nodes, torch.tensor([node]))) 
        self.actions = torch.cat((self.actions, torch.tensor([action]))) 
        self.rewards = torch.cat((self.rewards, torch.tensor([reward]))) 
    def episode_reward(self, episode_reward):
        self.rewards = torch.cat((self.rewards, torch.tensor([episode_reward])))
```

losses.py

```
class Losses():
    def log_trajectory_balance(trajectory):
        loss =  trajectory.log_norm_constant + trajectory.forward_probs.sum() - trajectory.backward_probs.sum() 
        return loss
    
    def trajectory_balance(trajectory):
        loss = trajectory.forward_probs[0]
        return loss

    def step_test(step):
        loss = step['forward_prob']
        return loss
```

I can share more code upon request but don't think it is necessary.